# Unable to Connect with MongoDB Atlas from Local Node App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have created a cluster on atlas and attempted to connect using my node app and log the connection status with mongoose. I have whitelisted my ip and set everything up properly but I keep getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Here's my code for `db.js`. Error throws on `mongooose.connect(url, opts)`.

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const db_connect = async () => {
 const conn_string = await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://devjoe: 
    <password_hidden_delibarately>@devcamper-gs1nb.mongodb.net/devcamper?retry 
    Writes=true&w=majority', 
   {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
   }); 

   console.log(`connection string: ${conn_string.connection.host}`);

}

module.exports = db_connect;
```

In `server.js` file, I just called the function like `db_connect();` after importing with commonjs module.

Any help will be appreciated as I can't find what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, from your question, I just can tell you what in general causes this error: it is generally a promise not handled properly. Can you try this and let me know? `db_connect().then(()=>console.log("okay")). catch (()=>console.log(" not okay")) ;`

Comment: What about the connection string, is it not required?

Comment: It supposes to be at the same place you are calling, except, try to catch the possible errors!

Comment: The place where you call `db_connect()`, just replace with the given code and let me know!

Comment: Hey there, I have tested your code, but using localhost, and it works. maybe the problem is your string. Are you sure it is okay? I myself had several problems with those strings in the beginning.

Comment: I'm also thinking that's the issue cos previously I had used env vars but they weren't reflecting until I restarted VsCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this in case the solution does not work:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const db_connect = () => {
  try {
    const conn_string = mongoose.connect(
      "mongodb+srv://devjoe: <*****************>@devcamper-gs1nb.mongodb.net/devcamper?retry Writes=true&w=majority",
      {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      }
    );

    console.log(`connection string: ${conn_string.connection.host}`);
  } catch {
    console.log(`not connected to : ${conn_string.connection.host}`);
  }
};

module.exports = db_connect;
```

I have just tested this solution in my computer, and it works!

But, in case none of that works, can send you how I do the connection.

Comment: It's not connecting either. Error thrown is at this point db_connect in server.js

Comment: So, allowing all ips seemed to be the solution. Hmm, wonder what my ip issue was. Thanks for the help though.